# Css based dropdown menu: incorrect width of <li> elements

Tags: css

Need to fix width problem of  `<li>`elements in this drop down menu. All `<li>`s must have the same width as the top `<li>` (MENU1, MENU2, MENU3) + must have the same size on mouse over.

It works correctly only if `#mymenu ul li a` have fixed width. When I change it's width to 100%, all `<li>`s have different width.

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq8ay2L6/)

css:

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,button,textarea,p,blockquote{padding:0;margin:0;}
body{cursor:default;font:11px/13px verdana,tahoma,arial;color:#333;background-color:#ffffff;}

div#mymenus{margin:0px auto;width:968px;height:36px;background:#5B4B40;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#776753, #5B4B40);background: -o-linear-gradient(#776753, #5B4B40);background: -moz-linear-gradient(#776753, #5B4B40);background: linear-gradient(#776753, #5B4B40);border:1px solid #362D26;border-radius:3px;z-index:999}
#mymenu,#mymenu ul{list-style:none;}
#mymenu{float:left;font-family:Arial;}
#mymenu > li{float:left;}
#mymenu li a{padding:11px 10px 12px 10px;text-decoration:none;position:relative; display:inline-block;}
#mymenu ul {position:absolute;display:none;z-index:999;border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px;}
#mymenu ul li a{width:100%;font-size:12px;color:#000;}
#mymenu li:hover ul{display:block;}
#mymenu > li > a{color: #fff;font-weight:700;}
#mymenu > li:hover > a{background:#EAD593;color:#000;} 
#mymenu ul li:hover a{background:#FFC97C;}
.lsub:nth-child(odd){background-color:#EFDEAB}
.lsub:nth-child(even){background-color:#EAD593;}
```

html:

```
<div id="mymenus">
<ul id="mymenu">
<li><a href="/">MENU ONE</a></li>
<li><a href="/">MENU TWO</a>
<ul>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu1</a></li>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu2</a></li>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="/">MENU THREE</a>
<ul>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu1</a></li>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu2</a></li>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="/">MENU FOUR</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your drop down list is inheriting your parent list style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the `<li>` and `<ul>` tags add this code:

```
#mymenu li a{padding:11px 10px 12px 10px;text-decoration:none;position:relative; display:block;}
#mymenu ul {position:relative;display:none;z-index:999;border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px;}
#mymenu ul li a{font-size:12px;color:#000;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lq8ay2L6/5/

Comment: This only makes the submenu items all the same, they aren't the same width as the MENU TWO/MENU THREE links at the top, which is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: when I change it to "auto", on mouse over the background is not the same size as li. It looks OK because all texts of "submenu" are of the same width. Try to replace "Submenu2" with just 1 letter and then mouse over.

Comment: Did you checked my latest fiddle? Number 5. iI have fixed that error. For example: If I add more later after MENU THREE the submenu inherits the width of it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,button,textarea,p,blockquote{padding:0;margin:0;}
body{cursor:default;font:11px/13px verdana,tahoma,arial;color:#333;background-color:#ffffff;}

div#mymenus{margin:0px auto;width:968px;height:36px;background:#5B4B40;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#776753, #5B4B40);background: -o-linear-gradient(#776753, #5B4B40);background: -moz-linear-gradient(#776753, #5B4B40);background: linear-gradient(#776753, #5B4B40);border:1px solid #362D26;border-radius:3px;z-index:999}
#mymenu,#mymenu ul{list-style:none;}
#mymenu{float:left;font-family:Arial;}
#mymenu > li{float:left; position: relative;}
#mymenu li a{padding:11px 10px 12px 10px;text-decoration:none;position:relative; display:inline-block;}
#mymenu ul {position:absolute;display:none;z-index:999;border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
width: 100%;
}
#mymenu ul li a{width:100%;font-size:12px;color:#000; box-sizing: border-box;}
#mymenu li:hover ul{display:block;}
#mymenu > li > a{color: #fff;font-weight:700;    }
#mymenu > li:hover > a{background:#EAD593;color:#000;} 
#mymenu ul li:hover a{background:#FFC97C;}
.lsub:nth-child(odd){background-color:#EFDEAB}
.lsub:nth-child(even){background-color:#EAD593;}
```

```html
<div id="mymenus">
<ul id="mymenu">
<li><a href="/">MENU ONE</a></li>
<li><a href="/">MENU TWO</a>
<ul>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu1</a></li>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu2</a></li>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="/">MENU THREE</a>
<ul>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu1</a></li>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu2</a></li>
<li class="lsub"><a href="/">Submenu3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="/">MENU FOUR</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lq8ay2L6/6/